# $\mathbb{R} \to S^1 \times S^1$ defined by $t \mapsto (e^{2\pi i \alpha t}, e^{2 \pi it})$ is not an embedding

Tags: general-topology

This is exercise $2.8.2$ from *Topology and Groupoids* by Ronald Brown.

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle in the complex plane and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be irrational. I want to show that $f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1 \times S^1, t \mapsto (e^{2\pi i \alpha t}, e^{2 \pi it})$ is not an embedding.

From definitions, there are a few ways to show that $f$ is not am embedding. I can show that an open (closed) set in $\mathbb{R}$ is not taken to an open (closed) set in $S^1 \times S^1$. I can also show that $f$ does not admit a continuous inverse.

I think the key to the problem is understanding how $\alpha$ irrational affects the mapping, but I can't figure out what it's doing. I've tried considering the sets $(0, 1/4)$ and $[0, 1/4]$, but am having trouble showing whether they are closed/open in $S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: The map $f$ is never surjective, so I think you are to show that $f$ is not embedding onto its image.

Comment: The property of $f$ that fails is the existence of a continuous inverse.  Try the metric-space notion of continuity.

Comment: John, the definition of an embedding in the book is a homeomorphism between f and its image. @Omnomnomnom, the metric space topology has not been defined yet in the book so I'd prefer a solution which does not appeal to it.

Comment: @shuckles how do you define the topology on $S^1$, then?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The subspace topology. A set $U \subset S^1$ is open if there exists an open $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U = M \cap S^1$

Comment: And the topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is defined via a metric, no?

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point. Let me think about your suggestion regarding inverses.

Comment: See also [shredding the torus](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/shredding.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

The map $f:\Bbb R\to S^1\times S^1$ sending $t$ to 
$$(f_1(t),f_2(t))=\left(e^{2\pi i \alpha t}, e^{2\pi i t}\right)$$ is injective because if $e^{2\pi i s}=e^{2\pi i t}$, then $s-t$ must be an integer, but then $\alpha s-\alpha t$ cannot be an integer, so $e^{2\pi i \alpha s}$ is distinct from $e^{2\pi i\alpha t}$, except when $s=t$.

So we need to show that $f:\Bbb R\to f(\Bbb R)$ is not open. Consider the image of the open interval $(-1,1)$. It contains $(e^0,e^0)$, but no other pair $(a,e^0)$. The aim is to show that $(e^0,e^0)$ is not interior point of $f((-1,1))$. So look at a neighborhood $U\times U$ of $(e^0,e^0)$, where $U$ is the image of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ under the (open) map 
$$\phi:\Bbb R\to S^1,\quad t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$$
Then $U=\phi\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)\right)$. Note that $f_1$ factors as $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\xrightarrow\phi S^1$, where the first map is multiplication by $\alpha$. If you can show that the product $\alpha l$ for some integer $l\ne 0$ is in an $\epsilon$-interval around some integer $k$, then $f(l)$ will be in $U\times\{e^0\}\setminus f((-1,1))$, and you are finished ([Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) may be useful here).

Comment: I can see that $f(l)$ will be in $U \times \{ e^0 \} \setminus f((-1, 1))$, but I'm not sure how that proves that $f((-1, 1))$ is not a neighborhood of $(e^0, e^0)$.

Comment: Every neighborhood $V$ of $(e^0,e^0)$ contains such a $U\times\{e^0\}$, so this shows that the relative neighborhood $f(\Bbb R)\cap V$ is not contained in $f((-1,1))$, implying that $f((-1,1))$ is not open.